# How to fix issue with Express error handler not being called

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, error-handling

I know this question is being repeated again. I've already looked at other solutions and tried them already. I'd appreciate your help in debugging the issue.

I've a separate `errorHandler` as a middleware.

error-handler.ts:

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export const errorHandler = (
  err: Error, 
  req: express.Request, 
  res: express.Response, 
  next: express.NextFunction
) => {
  console.log('Something went wrong');
  res.status(400).send({
    message: err.message
  });
}
```

index.ts:

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { json } from 'body-parser';
import { currentUserRouter } from './routes/current-user';
import { signinRouter } from './routes/signin';
import { signoutRouter } from './routes/signout';
import { signupRouter } from './routes/singup';
import { errorHandler } from './middlewares/error-handlers';

const app = express();
app.use(json());

app.use(currentUserRouter);
app.use(signinRouter);
app.use(signoutRouter);
app.use(signupRouter);

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!!!');
})
```

When an `Error` is thrown, the Express is not catching it.

signup.ts:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
const router = express.Router();
import { body, validationResult } from "express-validator";

const bodyValidation = [
  body('email')
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage('Email must be valid'),
  body('password')
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 4, max: 20})
    .withMessage('Password must be between 4 and 20 characters')
];

router.post('/api/users/signup', bodyValidation, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
    throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
  }
  
  console.log('Creating a user...');

  res.send({});
});

export { router as signupRouter }
```

I can see `Error: Invalid email or password` in the terminal being thrown. But Express is not catching the error being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express doesn't pay any attention to the return value of your route handler. You're passing an `async` function to `router.post`, which means that your function will return a promise to report its completion, **rather than** reporting it in the usual synchronous way. So any error thrown within the function is reported via the promise — which Express ignores.

In general, it's not a good idea to pass an `async` function to something as a callback if that something (Express, in this case) doesn't support handling the `Promise` the function returns.

In your example, you don't have any code using `await`, so you could just remove the `async`.

If you have code using `await` that you left out to keep the question brief (which was perfectly reasonable), you might make that an inner function you call and use the promise from:

```
router.post("/api/users/signup", bodyValidation, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
    }

    console.log("Creating a user...");
    (async () => {
        // ...your code using `await` here...

        // You're all done, send the result
        res.send({});
    })().catch((error) => {
        // ...send error response...
    });
});
```

Note how that code catches promise rejection in order to send an error response — you wouldn't want to just leave the promise rejection unhandled.

Another way you can do that is to ensure that the **entire** body of that inner function is in a `try`/`catch`:

```
router.post("/api/users/signup", bodyValidation, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
    }

    console.log("Creating a user...");
    (async () => {
        try {
            // ...your code using `await` here...

            // You're all done, send the result
            res.send({});
        } catch (error) {
            // ...send error response...
        }
    })();
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I didn't `async` function might cause so much trouble!