# App is getting crashed on duplicate response, Error is not catched

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to Add a user I created this Auth.js File while hitting this endpoint from thunderclient the error must me catched and a res.json must be sent which is not happening what should i do:

Auth.js

```
const express=require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router=express.Router();
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');


router.post('/',[
        body('email').isEmail(),
        body('name').isLength({ min: 5 }),
        body('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], async (req, res)=>{
        try{
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
      
        User.create({
                name: req.body.name,
                password: req.body.password,
                email: req.body.email
              }).then(user => res.json(user));
        
        }
        catch(errors) { 
                console.error(errors)
                res.json({error:'Please Use A Unique Value'})
        }

        

})


module.exports = router
```

Comment: return callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(res.writeErrors[0]));
                                ^

MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: inotebook.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "us@nootik.com" }
    at 
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { email: 1 },
  keyValue: { email: 'us@nootik.com' },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.8.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: what are you getting in response in thunderclient?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not making async operations in your router, express is ignoring errors returned from your `router.post` method as it is being treated as a promise.

You need to remove `async` keyword and make your route synchronous:

```
const express=require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router=express.Router();
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');


router.post('/',[
        body('email').isEmail(),
        body('name').isLength({ min: 5 }),
        body('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res)=>{  // removed async keyword
        try{
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
      
        User.create({
                name: req.body.name,
                password: req.body.password,
                email: req.body.email
              }).then(user => res.json(user));
        
        }
        catch(errors) { 
                console.error(errors)
                res.json({error:'Please Use A Unique Value'})
        }

        

})
```

Comment: Also, answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75200762/how-to-fix-issue-with-express-error-handler-not-being-called/75200815#75200815